# Java declaration confusion for datatypes

Tags: java

I have a doubt about null assigning to variable in Java. In my program I have assigned null to String variable as `String str_variable = null;`.  For the learning purpose i assigned null integer variable as `int int_variable = null;` It shows error `Add cast with Integer`. So that rewrite the above int declaration as `Integer int_variable = null;`. This does not shows errors. I do not know the reason of these two kind of declaration.

Please the difference between to me.

```
String str_variable = null;

int int_variable = null; // error.

Integer int_variable1 = null; // no error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String and Integer are both classes, in a way they are not native data types that is why it is always okay for you to set null as an initial value, however for int you must always initialize it with a number, one good way to find out their appropriate initialization value is to create variables outside your main(), example String var1; int var2; then use System.out.println(var1); System.out.println(var2); within the main()
to see what was placed as an initial value when you run the program.

Comment: thanks i get idea of it. what is wrapper class? what is the different between other class and wrapper class in java?

Comment: when you try to picture a wrapper class a simple analogy can be formed, native data type -> Class -> Wrapper Class, simply put a wrapper class is a class built over another class, or it is an expansion of a class built to serve another purpose

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a primitive, `Integer` is a class.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a **primitive type**, `Integer` is a **wrapper class** type extending `Object` class. Non-referencing objects can be `null` but primitives cannot. That's why you get an error message saying you need **casting**.

You can use a line like `int num = (Integer) null;`, this is how casting is done, however you will get `NullPointerException` when you try to use `num` anywhere in your code since a non-referencing(null) `Integer` object **doesn't hold / wrap** a primitive value.

Comment: thanks. what is wrapper class? what is the different between other class and wrapper class in java?

Comment: Wrapper classes are used to represent primitive values (int, long, boolean, ..) when you need an object of them.